# Migrating from UIKit to SwiftUI

Tags: swift, inheritance, swiftui, uikit

I have a view controller which is inherited from BaseViewController. Now as I'm converting UIKit to SwiftUI I need my class to inherit from my SwiftUIView class.

Before:

```
class CountryLanguageViewController: BaseViewController {}
```

After:

```
class CountryLanguageViewController: UIHostingController<SelectCountrySwiftUIView> {}
```

I cannot have multiple inheritance here with baseVC and SwiftUI class. but I also want things to be inherited from BaseVC. How this can be achieved?

Comment: From the looks of it, you are just converting only a small part of your `CountryLanguageViewController` (a single subview?) to use SwiftUI views, and not the entire view that `CountryLanguageViewController` controls? If so, you can probably just add the `UIHostingController` as a child VC of your VC.

Comment: SwiftUI `Views` are not classes, they are `struct` and so you cannot inherit from them.

Comment: @Sweeper no i'm converting whole page to swiftUI as a part of my app migration.

Comment: @workingdogsupportUkraine so how would I be able to use/create base class functions in swiftUI as we use in swift?

Comment: So why do you still use `BaseViewController`? Or `UIViewController`s at all. If you are converting the whole app to SwiftUI, there should be no view controllers at all.

Comment: you can create any base class functions you want, to do processing etc..., but not inheriting from a SwiftUI `View`. You need to understand the differnces in concepts, between UIKit and SwiftUI. As mentioned, there are no controllers and such in SwiftUI.

Comment: Maybe read [the tutorials](https://developer.apple.com/tutorials/swiftui) first and understand SwiftUI's paradigm if you haven't already.

Comment: yes @Sweeper i'm going one by one.. so need to know a way for baseVC in swiftUI

Comment: Okay, so what is in `BaseViewController`? You need to actually show what it does for anyone to give a somewhat satisfying answer.

Comment: Most part of VC is the logic of the app and should go in models in SwiftUI. Try first to separate logic of VC from view contents.

Comment: okay @Sweeper baseVC is containing app level designs for navigationbar, tabbar, alerts, loaders etc.

Comment: @PtitXav okay ill try to add some models with this code

Comment: SwiftUI views are not classes they can’t be inherited

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you want to do it the other way round:

You need to make your UIKIt CountryLanguageViewController 'rendered' with SwiftUI. You can achieve this with [UIViewControllerRepresentable](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/uiviewcontrollerrepresentable)

So your code will look something like:

```
struct SelectCountrySwiftUIView: UIViewControllerRepresentable {

    func makeUIViewController(context: Context) -> CountryLanguageViewController {
        CountryLanguageViewController()
    }

    func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: CountryLanguageViewController, context: Context) {
        // NO OP
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how I got the result—and after updating all of the old `uiviewcontroller`s with SwiftUI, I updated them with SwiftUI ‘s navigation. Why do you need `weak var viewController: UIViewController?`? It can be used to close a window or open another `uiviewcontroller` window in the SwiftUI view!

**Set your `SwiftuiView`**

```
import SwiftUI

struct YourView: View {
    weak var viewController: UIViewController?
```

**Create new `ViewController` view for `UIHostingController`**

```
import SwiftUI

class MyViewController: UIHostingController<YourView> {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

}
```

**How you use in the old `UIViewcontroller` class**

```
let vc = MyViewController(rootView: YourView(viewController: self))
```

You have full access this `viewcontroller` here:

[image: you have full access this viewcontroller here]

[This is my AppRputer package](https://gitlab.com/azimxxm/UIKitToSwiftUIAppRouter)